# Unable to import win32com.client despite having installed pywin32 in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, pywin32

I am trying to import win32com.client but vscode shows that it couldnt find the module.

`Import "win32com.client" could not be resolved`

I have opened VScode in a virtual environment using anaconda. I have installed pywin32 through conda and the vscode terminal as well and the same message was shown.

`Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in f:\anaconda\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages (228)`

I have gone through all the posts with the same error and their problem seems to have been solved by just installing pywin32. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lied with vscode not actually being in the virtual environment. Click on the python version shown on the status bar at bottom left of the screen and select the venv you want to fix the error.